# “Unterwegs” or “auf dem Weg”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between *auf dem Weg* and *unterwegs*?

> Ich bin unterwegs/auf dem Weg nach Hause.

Comment: "Auf dem Weg" also means to walk in an area designated  for walking, as opposed to "walking on the lawn".

Answer (score 10):

In their adverbial usage, they are entirely synonymous.

> Ich habe unterwegs/auf dem Weg Hans getroffen.
>
> "Kommst Du endlich?" -- "Schon unterwegs/auf dem Weg!"
>
> "Hast Du schon etwas gegessen?" -- "Nein, das mache ich unterwegs/auf dem Weg."

I can think of one usage where only one of the two works:

> "Kannst Du bitte nachher den Brief einwerfen? Die Post liegt doch **auf dem Weg**.

Comment: Downvotes without comments are rude. :(

Answer (score 7):

There is a **difference when used without giving a destination**:

> Ich bin auf dem Weg.
>   Ich bin unterwegs.

While

- *auf dem Weg* implies that you are **going somewhere**,
- *unterwegs* is not implicating any direction/destination.
  You can used even if you are randomly walking/driving/.. around

As mentioned *auf dem Weg* can be used literally if something is actually *on the way* (see example by elena)

Otherwise it is used synonymously.

Comment: +1. I've seen "unterwegs" used where "on the move" or "on the go" would also fit in English -- e.g., in advertising for a mobile banking app.  (But I'm not a native or even good German speaker, so beware.)

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting common etymology of the German *"[unterwegs](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GU11854)"*, and the English *"on the way"*:

> Old High German: **underwegen**
>   Dutch: **onderweg**
>   English: **on the way**

Note the change of **u** to **o**. Still in the 16th Century *"under Wegen"* was used in Germany. Today *"unter dem Weg"* would be used for a location below a way. Only if used with the preposition *"auf"* both, *"auf dem Weg"*, and *"unterwegs"* [are synonyms](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8109/23) in contemporary German.

Today, the English [underway](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/underway) has a different, figurative meaning (*in Bearbeitung, im Gange*).

Comment: Dutch "Op weg" is common too.